# How to mock a DB connection in RestController Test?

Tags: java, spring, rest, testing, mocking

I have a Rest controller GET method

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepo.findAll()
}
```

I need to test it, but I get the "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured". The problem is that the nature of production does not allow me to use real connection or change it to embedded one. Is there a way to mock the DB somehow?

 The project is almost the same to the one in this article:
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-rest-api-with-spring-boot

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to create an embedded one for a test? IF you really want you can run an `@WebMvcTest` and use an `@MockBean` for the `UserRepository` you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the WebMvcTest advice, really helped

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `@MockBean` annotation to mock the `UserRepository` or you can create an embedded in-memory H2 DB for the test by adding following properties in `application-test.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

You can follow [this link](https://programmingtechie.com/2020/10/21/spring-boot-testing-tutorial-database-testing-with-test-containers/) to understand it in detail.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the mock annotation, it was really useful. I guess what I haven't figured out was that I needed to use the @...MVCTest, not the RestTest, so it really was a push in the right direction